# How can a lens satisfy the Fraunhofer diffraction condition by making a distance negative?

Tags: interference, geometric-optics, diffraction, lenses, huygens-principle

There has been a bit of discussion about this already, however, my question arises more from the mathematical requirements to allow for Fraunhofer diffraction proposed by Born and Wolf's optics book.

First: variable definitions: Given $r'$ is the distance of the source from the aperture and $s'$ is the distance of resultant pattern, and $(\zeta, \eta)$ as the aperture coordinates, and $l_0, l$ and $m, m_0$ as direction cosines of the aperture to the source/point (these are not terribly important for the discussion).

The quadratic (Fresnel) phase can be ignored under the following condition:

$\frac{1}{2} k | (\frac{1}{r'} + \frac{1}{s'}))(\zeta^2 + \eta^2) - \frac{(l_0\zeta + m_0 \eta)^2}{r'} - \frac{(l\zeta + m\eta)^2}{s'}| << 2\pi$

There are two possibilities:

(1) The distance of the source and the resulting diffraction are observed very far away relative to the aperture size divided by the wavelength, i.e.

$|r'| >> (\zeta^2 + \eta^2)_{max}/\lambda$

$|s'| >> (\zeta^2 + \eta^2)_{max}/\lambda$

This one is very familiar and intuitive: clean, constructive interference off the small slit is successfully achieved with planar waves incident on the aperture and observed far enough away.

(2) The other possibility to satisfy this is:

$\frac{1}{r'} + \frac{1}{s'} = 0$ and the angle of the source/observation are very paraxial.

The 2nd condition is very confusing, however, it seems vital to justify the usage of a lens i.e. an ideal lens placed after the aperture will always satisfy the Fraunhofer condition. ***How can these distances be negative?*** If a point source is imaged by a lens, the image plane will reconstruct this point source. But how can this end up making $r'$ negative? From geometric optics, I know that we can interpret the image as being an additional point source, but wouldn't r' stay a positive quantity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read further in the section 4.3.3 in your "Born & Wolf" from which you have quoted the equations you will find this paragraph on page 427, ($P_0$ is the location of the source):

> Conditions (33) give an estimate of the distances r' and s' for which the Fraunhofer
> representation may be used. Conditions (34) imply that Fraunhofer diffraction also
> occurs when the point of observation is situated in a plane parallel to that of the
> aperture, provided that both the point of observation and the source are sufficiently
> close to the $z$-axis. Here two cases may be distinguished: When $r'$ is negative, the
> wave-fronts incident upon the aperture are concave to the direction of the propagation,
> i.e. $P_0$ is a centre of convergence and not of divergence of the incident wave. This case
> is of great practical importance, as it arises in the image space of a well-corrected
> centred system that images a point source which is not far from the axis. A Fraunhofer
> pattern is then formed in the Gaussian image plane and may be considered as arising
> from the diffraction of the image-forming wave on the exit pupil. When $r'$ is positive,
> the wave-fronts are convex to the direction of propagation. The diffraction phenomena
> are virtual, being apparently formed on a screen through the source $P_0$. This case
> arises, for example, when an aperture is held in front of the eye, or the object glass of a
> telescope adjusted for distant vision of the light source.

The sign *convention* is visible and explained by Figure 8.3b. showing the angles between the aperture plane normal and the radius vectors. If you flip the source point $P_0$ to the same side as where $P$ is, then the sign of  the cosine angle between the normal and the radius vector is also flipped. In short, the source having a negative distance from the aperture just means a *concave* wavefront is propagating along the direction of propagation.

Comment: Ok that's very helpful, I see how the cosine term can justify the sign convention. But, if you a have point source --> aperture --> lens, the point source is still physically behind the screen isn't it? In that paragraph, there's a confusing jump in logic, how does a lens suddenly make the source come from the final image? The only way I can justify this that the image of the source acts as an additional source, but that doesn't seem physically sound to me

Comment: The point source of a concave wavefront is at a "virtual" point, it is nowhere in a real space... But imagine a plane wave hitting a concave lens whose *virtual* focus is $P_0$, the resulting wavefront is concave spherical centered at $P_0$.